# Jquery input element simulate keydown

Tags: jquery, keydown

I just write the following code to test if the juqery code of key ENTER  function simulation works:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Test()
        {
          var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e.keyCode = 13;
          $("#test_id").trigger(e);
       }
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="get" id="form" action="http://www.twitter.com">
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id" id="test_id" />
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id1" id="test_id1" />
           <button type="submit">go</button>
        </form>
        <a href="javascript:Test()"  id="btn_nfc" ><font size="10">Test</font></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if the code works correctly, then it will redirect to twitter.com, but actually when I click the button "Test", nothing happened, is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: why you need jquery for that? on submit it will hit the action?

Comment: @TechBreak yes, for submit, it is ok, but there are somewhere that do not have the form or submit, so actually I try to simulate the "Enter" keydown event

Answer (score 1):

You should use your keydown event on the form rather then the test link. Try this code below

```js
$(function(){
    $('form').on('keydown', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('testing');
      }
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="get" id="form" action="http://www.twitter.com">
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id" id="test_id" />
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id1" id="test_id1" />
           <button type="submit">go</button>
        </form>
        <a href="javascript:Test()"  id="btn_nfc" ><font size="10">Test</font></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, the alert function works well, but nothing else happen, while when we press "enter" key in the input, it will go to the new url page

Comment: You want to redirect to twitter.com right, is it not redirecting. It sure is not in the snippet but try this in your code and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you wish to programmatically submit the form.

But I will explain your current code first.

Inside the `Test()` function, you are triggering the `keydown` event of the textbox and nothing happened. Since you don't have any `keydown` event handler specified to the textbox like the one `("#test_id").on('keydown', function(e) { })`

I have given such an `event handler` and you can see, this is getting executed when you click the `Test` link.

You can test the redirect to `twitter` with help of a web page created locally in your machine and copying the below code.

To submit the form on the `keydown` event, `$( "#form" ).submit()` is used below inside the `event handler` which you can directly use inside the `Test` function if you intent to programmatically submit the form rather than registering the `keydown` event handler and trigger it from the `Test` function.

You can use like this,

```
       function Test()
        {
          $( "#form" ).submit();
       }
```

**Code**:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Test()
        {
          // You can uncomment and use the one liner to submit the form
          //$( "#form" ).submit();

          var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e.keyCode = 13;
          $("#test_id").trigger(e);
       }
  
       // registering 'keydown' event handler
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#test_id").on('keydown', function(e) {
           if(e.keyCode === 13) {
             console.log('Form submitted');
             $( "#form" ).submit();
           }
         });
       });
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="get" id="form" action="http://www.twitter.com">
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id" id="test_id" />
           <input type="text" value="" name="test_id1" id="test_id1" />
           <button type="submit">go</button>
        </form>
        <a href="javascript:Test()"  id="btn_nfc" ><font size="10">Test</font></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are right,  when there is not any jquery code in the file, and we press the "Enter" key in the input element, the page will redirect to the new url, so I just want to simulate the "Enter" key event.  BTW, I know that sumit function can work well, but there are are somewhere that do not contain form or submit.